# How can I access windows files on an ubuntu live boot

Tags: dual-boot

I'm using a live boot of ubuntu and want to access some programs that I already had installed on my computer. It was windows 10 and I want to use some programs I installed but cant find out how to access them, I know I can reinstall it but if I reboot or leave the live boot it wont be saved.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Your question title and the body do not match. Running programs is not the same as accessing files. Please edit your question and clarify.

Answer (score 2):

Windows software won't run in Ubuntu (let alone a live session) just like that. Some may work when installed directly in Ubuntu with the help of Wine.

You can't run software installed in a Windows partition from a Ubuntu live session.

Comment: Well, in theory you could, but it would be much more complicated than it's worth except for the experiment or learning experience.

Answer (score 0):

I am surprised nobody has made this suggestion yet:

**Use a Windows 10 Virtual Machine inside Ubuntu**

You can always back up your files to the cloud and redownload them on the virtual machine, you can try and make an ISO for the virtual machine with your files in it (have fun with that lol) or you can try and use things like Guest Additions and passthrough filters that allow you to transfer files between Host and Guest OS.

(This requires at least 30GB of storage)

Comment: Running a virtual machine from a **live Ubuntu boot** would be rather difficult.

Comment: @raj weighing it up against the difficulty of getting OP's programs to all run on WINE though, I'd say it is a pretty safe bet.

Comment: @MaybeLBDidIt have you ever tried running a virtual machine inside a Live Ubuntu session? If it worked please provide the details in your answer.

Comment: @user68186 yeahhhh thats a bit too long to put here, sorry